# Interleaving FFT real & complex parts in a PyTorch tensor

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, slice

I have a use-case where I have to do FFT for a given tensor as. Here, FFT is applied to each of the 10 rows, in a column-wise manner which gives the dimension (10, 11) post FFT.

```
# Random data-
x = torch.rand((10, 20))

# Compute RFFT of 'x'-
x_fft = torch.fft.rfft(x)

# Sanity check-
x.shape, x_fft.shape
# (torch.Size([10, 20]), torch.Size([10, 11]))

# FFT for the first 2 rows are-
x_fft[:2, :]
'''
tensor([[12.2561+0.0000j,  0.7551-1.2075j,  1.1119-0.0458j, -0.2814-1.5266j,
          1.4083-0.7302j,  0.6648+0.3311j,  0.3969+0.0632j, -0.8031-0.1904j,
         -0.4206+0.9066j, -0.2149+0.9160j,  0.4800+0.0000j],
        [ 9.8967+0.0000j, -0.5100-0.2377j, -0.6344+2.2406j,  0.4584-1.0705j,
          0.2235+0.4788j, -0.3923+0.8205j, -1.0372-0.0292j, -1.6368+0.5517j,
          1.5093+0.0419j,  0.5755-1.2133j,  2.9269+0.0000j]])
'''

# The goal is to have for each row, 1-D vector (of size = 11) as follows:
# So, for first row, the desired 1-D vector (size = 11) is-
[12.2561, 0.0000, 0.7551, -1.2075, 1.1119, -0.0458, -0.2814, -1.5266,
1.4083, -0.7302, 0.6648, 0.3311, 0.3969, 0.0632, -0.8031, -0.1904,
-0.4206, 0.9066, -0.2149, 0.9160, 0.4800, 0.0000]
'''
```

Here, you are taking the real and imaginary components and placing them adjacent to each other.

Adjacent means:

```
[a_1_real, a_1_imag, a_2_real, a_2_imag, a_3_real, a_3_imag, ....., a_n_real, a_n_imag]
```

Since for each row, you get 11 FFT complex numbers, a_n = a_11.

How to go about it?

Comment: What do you mean by adjacent to each other?

Comment: @Ivan edited question to explain it

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to come down to: how to interleave two tensors together. Given `x` and `y` the two tensors. You can do so with a combination of [`transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html) and [`reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html).

```
>>> torch.stack((x,y),1).transpose(1,2).reshape(2,-1)
tensor([[ 1.1547e+01,  0.0000e+00,  1.3786e+00, -8.1970e-01, -3.2118e-02,
         -2.3900e-02, -3.2898e-01, -3.4610e-01, -1.7916e-01,  1.2308e+00,
         -5.4203e-01,  1.2580e-01,  8.5273e-01,  8.9980e-01, -2.7096e+00,
         -3.8060e-01,  3.0016e-01, -4.5240e-01, -7.7809e-02,  4.5630e-01,
         -4.5805e-03,  0.0000e+00],
        [ 1.1106e+01,  0.0000e+00,  1.3362e-01,  1.3830e-01, -7.4233e-01,
          7.7570e-01, -9.9461e-01,  1.0834e+00,  1.6952e+00,  5.2920e-01,
         -1.1884e+00, -2.5970e-01, -8.7958e-01,  4.3180e-01, -9.3039e-01,
          8.8130e-01, -1.0048e+00,  1.2823e+00,  2.0595e-01, -6.5170e-01,
          1.7209e+00,  0.0000e+00]])
```

Comment: edited question to hopefully make it more clear

Comment: Solved ```torch.dstack([x_fft.real, x_fft.imag]).view(10, 11 * 2)```; [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/interleaving-fft-real-complex-parts-in-a-tensor/153103/3)